# iPhone - comparing dates not working as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have an event that is set to a particular date. I want to check if the date is within 5 minutes range of the current date. For example: if the event is set to 9:10 pm, and now is 9:02 pm. I want to see if the current time is between 9:05 and 9:15 pm.

So, I do...

```
NSDate *currentDate ... this variable contains the current date
NSDate *plusFive = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:300];
NSDate *minusFive = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-300];

NSComparisonResult result1 = [eventDate compare:minusFive];
NSComparisonResult result2 = [eventDate compare:plusFive];


if ( (result1 == NSOrderedAscending) && (result2 == NSOrderedDescending) ) { 
    // if the current date is not inside the 5 minutes window
    // or in other words, if the currentDate is lower than minusFive and bigger
    // than plusFive
    [self currentDateIsOutsideTheWindow];
} else {
    [self currentDateIsInsideTheWindow];
}
```

the problem is that result1 and result2 always gives me NSOrderedAscending as a result, for any date.

Any clues?

thanks.

Comment: Why are you using `eventDate` instead of `currentDate`?

Comment: I added a quick code example to my answer... the date's `compare:` method seems to be working as expected for me, but I'd suggest simplifying your code as suggested in the answers anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
NSTimeInterval ti = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
if (ti > 0 && ti < 300) ...
else if (ti < 0 && ti > -300) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should switch around eventDate and currentDate in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I think EmptyStack's solution is the best for this problem, but I'd just simplify it as follows:

```
if( fabs([eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) <= 300.0 ) {
  // within the window
} else {
  // outside the window
}
```

I was curious about this... so I wrote a quick test and everything works as expected for me. Given the sample code below, in the first run, the plus five is `NSOrderedAscending` when compared with now, as expected, and the minus five is `NSOrderedDescending`. In the second run, plus five is `NSOrderedAscending` and minus five is `NSOrderedDescending` when compared with a date three minutes from now. Finally, plus five is `NSOrderedDescending` and minus five is also `NSOrderedDescending` when compared with a date twenty minutes from now, again, all as expected.

```
// datetest.m
// clang -o datetest datetest.m -framework foundation

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void test_compare(NSDate* event_date)
{
    NSDate* dateNow = [NSDate date];

    NSDate* minusFive = [event_date dateByAddingTimeInterval:-300.0];
    NSDate* plusFive = [event_date dateByAddingTimeInterval:300.0];

    NSComparisonResult minusFiveResult = [dateNow compare:minusFive];
    NSComparisonResult plusFiveResult = [dateNow compare:plusFive];

    NSLog(@"P5: %ld, M5: %ld; dates (now, event, p5, m5):\n\t%@\n\t%@\n\t%@\n\t%@", (long int)plusFiveResult, (long int)minusFiveResult, 
        dateNow, event_date, plusFive, minusFive);  
}

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    // test for an event that's "now"
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    test_compare(now);

    // test for an event that's three minutes from now
    NSDate* threeMinutesLater = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:180.0];
    test_compare(threeMinutesLater);

    // test for an event that's 20 minutes ago
    NSDate* twentyMinutesBefore = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1200.0];
    test_compare(twentyMinutesBefore);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```